# Algorithm challenge: Repeating a string

Tags: javascript

just learning JS and am going through Algorithm challenges.

The below code should repeat a string (str) x (num) times.

So for example repeatStringNumTimes('*', 3) should be '***'. 
The below code does that... but there is an 'undefined' word that appears in the beginning of the output. Why is that?! I've defined all variables...

```
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {

    let len = str.length;
    let string;

for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {

    for (let x = 0; x < len; x++) {

        string += str[x];

    }

}
return string;
}

console.log(repeatStringNumTimes('*', 10));
```

Comment: change `let string;` to `let string = "";` as string is `undefined` initially

Comment: think of `let string;` as being `let string = undefined`;

Answer (score 3):

> I've defined all variables

Yes you **define** it, but not **initialize**.

Default initalization in javascript is `undefined`.

So, `let a;` equals to `let a = undefined;`
You should initialize your strings with empty string:

```
let string = '';
```

---

*Just a note:*

Modern javascript engines have [String.prototype.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method for that task:

```
console.log('*'.repeat(10)); // **********
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to declare string:

```
let string = "";
```

UPDATE:

That is because of this line:

```
string += str[x];
```

Which equates to:

```
string = string + str[x]; 
// equivalent to string = undefined + str[x]
```

You are assigning an undefined string to itself (+ str[x]), if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you need to specify that? I ask only because of my lack of knowledge in JS.

Comment: Because of this line: `string += str[x];`You are basically adding the value of an undefined string + str[x] to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, in order to make this work I added

```
let string = "";
```

I'm not sure why that works though. Any insight from someone more experienced would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: String is initially `undefined` (never initialized). Then `string += str[x]` in the first loop, expands to `string = undefined + str[x]`

Answer (score 0):

Traditional approach using `while`

```js
const repeatStringNumTimes = (str, num) => {
  let res = str
  while (--num) res += str
  return res
}

console.log(repeatStringNumTimes('*', 10))
```

Using [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

```js
const repeatStringNumTimes = (str, num) => str.repeat(num)

console.log(repeatStringNumTimes('*', 10))
```

Using [`String.prototype.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) or [`String.prototype.padEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)

```js
const repeatStringNumTimes = (str, num) => ''.padStart(num, str)

console.log(repeatStringNumTimes('*', 10))
```

Using [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const repeatStringNumTimes = (str, num) => Array(num).join(str)

console.log(repeatStringNumTimes('*', 10))
```